# Microsoft Teams Tab Authentication with ADAL - can't get token in Teams DESKTOP app

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-teams, adal, azure-authentication

I'm working on a custom MS Teams Tab app, and inside it I need to get an authentication token from Azure.

I did it using "AuthenticationContext" from the 'adal-angular' library.
Relevant code:

```
var options: AuthenticationContext.Options = {
      clientId: this.properties.azureAppId,
      extraQueryParameter: "scope=openid+profile&login_hint=" + encodeURIComponent(this._teamsContext.loginHint),
      popUp: true,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin
    };
    
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(options);

authContext.acquireTokenPopup(authContext.config.loginResource, undefined, undefined, (errDesc, token, err) => {
  this.properties.azureAuthToken = token;
  // ... and so on...
```

This works fine for the Teams web client, but does not work in the Teams Desktop app.
In there, instead of a pop-up, a real tab gets opened in my default browser, but then the Teams Desktop app and the browser "loose track of each other".
After inspecting developer tools of the Teams Desktop app, I found that the "authContext.acquireTokenPopup" call fails, and the error message is "Popup Window is null. This can happen if you are using IE".

Can anybody help ? What else do I need to do, or is it even possible for this to work from the Teams Desktop app as well ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the redirect URL for your app in Azure?

Comment: here's the thing: my app is built with the sharepoint framework, and thus hosted in sharepoint ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/integrate-with-teams-introduction ). I don't think I know what link to use, how to set-up a distinct page inside my app...

Comment: You can directly give the SPFx page link to teams tab. make sure sharepoint domain is added to validDomain[] array of manifest and you have done Sync To Teams within your app catalog

Comment: more exactly, how do I do this ? could you point me to a working example ?
I can't seem to find a SPFx app with several pages...

Comment: Please check this documentation for [Build SharePoint webpart within Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab). You can add multiple webpart in your sharepoint page and add that as teams tab

Comment: I did read that, but there's no explanation about how to "navigate" from one web part to another, the same way you would navigate between 2 different pages of your web app...

Comment: Navigating from one webpart to another you can use [deep linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links) in your spfx webpart. That needs to handled in your spfx webpart tab code